# C# dynamics , array of objects

Tags: c#

is it possible to handle array of objects by using dynamics ?

I mean something like this ...\

```
dynamic d ;

d.SomeProp.Add(new SomeObject);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) to dynamically build an object at runtime:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.SomeProp = new List<SomeObject>();
d.SomeProp.Add(new SomeObject());
```

Can't quite see the point of this though, personally I would prefer to have strong typing and compile-time safety. How about you?